# Infinite Scroll not working with Browser Zoom

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll, intersection-observer

I implemented infinite scroll by using the following code to detect if the user scrolled to the bottom of the page.

```js
if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
  // ...
}
```

This works as it is supposed to, with one exception, which is the browser zoom. I am using Safari, and by chance I noticed that the condition is not true when I zoom in and then scroll to the bottom of the page. Is there a way to solve this problem? Or would this problem be solved when I use a different approach like the IntersectionObserverAPI?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, `window.scrollY + window.innerHeight` was always just one or two pixels short. I tried it out with a lot of different sized scrollable areas and zoom levels from 115 to 150 percent, and it does not seem to get more than that.

That means that, if you are okay with it triggering a few pixels before the exact bottom of the page, which, in my opinion, just makes the infinite scroll smoother, then you can simply add something to the value and it will work again.